# Consider the function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathcal P (\mathbb N)$ Given $f(n) = Ø$, What is the set D?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Full Question:**

Consider the function f : ℕ → ℘(ℕ) defined as f(n) = Ø. Trace through the formal proof of Cantor's theorem with this choice of f in mind. In the middle of the argument, the proof defines set D = { $ x \in S$ | $x \notin f(x)$} in terms of f. Given that f(n) = Ø, what is that set D? Provide your answer without using set-builder notation. Is it clear why f(n) ≠ D for any n ∈ ℕ?

This question is based of the proof of cantor's theorem.

I understood the theorem and applied the diagonalization used in cantor's theorem to this problem.

**My working:**

$n_1 \to$ {},
$n_2 \to$ {},
$n_3 \to$ {},
$n_4 \to$ {},
$n_5 \to$ {},
$n.._i \to$ {}

Therefore I concluded D = {Ø}, because every set was empty and I didn't have anything to "flip" when i used diagonalization.

The part I found tricky was how do you "flip" an empty set? I was wondering if someone can check this for me or tell me if i'm on the right track.

Comment: How is $D$ defined? Without knowing something *something* about $D$ this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I already had "D" defined in my working.

Comment: If $f(n) =\emptyset$, a constant function then $D= \{n\in \mathbb N|n \not \in f(n)\}=\{n\in \mathbb N|n\not \in \emptyset\} = \{n\in \mathbb N\} = \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual *formal* definition of a set $D$ that witnesses that a function $f:S\rightarrow P(S)$ was not surjective is
$$D=\{x\in S:x\not\in f(x)\}$$
You can imagine, in the case where $S=\mathbb N$, drawing a function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow P(\mathbb N)$ in the following way: for each natural number $n$, draw an infinite row of boxes labelled as $1,2,3,\ldots$. Color a box in this row black if that element is in the set $f(n)$ and leave it white otherwise. This gives a visual representation of a function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow P(\mathbb N)$: such functions are just ways to color a grid. The function you describe would be the coloring where every box is left white.

You're trying to show that there is some possible row of white/black boxes that does not appear as a row in the diagram you made before; Cantor's solution to this is to go down the diagonal of this - to the cells $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ and so on, and to create a new row whose colors are the *opposite* of those on the diagonal. This row can't be the first row because its first color is different, nor can it be the second, because the second color is wrong - and so on. Thus, it must be a new row that did not appear.

In the given situation, every square in the original grid was white, so the opposite of the diagonal is every square being black - hence would be the whole set. Thus $D=\mathbb N$ by this pictorial reasoning. Note that the empty set is not such a special choice - you still have the same grid, you just chose not to color it - so you still have something to "flip": a whole bunch of empty boxes!

In formal terms, you are trying to find those $x$ such that $x\not\in f(x)$. However, $f(x)=\emptyset$, so you really want to find those $x$ such that $x\not\in \emptyset$. Nothing is in the empty set, so this is just every $x$ in the domain, which is $\mathbb N$ in this case. Moreover, you should be really concerned if you try to construct $D$ and find out that it was in the image of $f$ - because the whole point of $D$ is that it's *definitely* not!

Comment: Where did you learn the example of the coloring grid from? Is something like this online? The explanation made a lot of sense.

Comment: @jame_smith It's something I came up with while teaching set theory - I, unfortunately, don't know of any set theory references that offer much in the way of visualization or this kind of "concrete" explanation of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n)=\emptyset$ then $n\not \in f(n) = \emptyset$ ever. So the set of all $n \not \in f(n)$ is the set of all $n$ or $\mathbb N$.

$D = \mathbb N$.

As for why $\mathbb N \ne f(n) = \emptyset$ ... well, other than the obvious, ....

I think we *aren't* supposed to actually figure out what $D$ is.

If $f(n) = D$ for some $n$, then $D= \emptyset$ so that means there is *no* $n$ so that $n \not \in f(n)$ so that means *all* $n \in f(n)$ but all $f(n) = \emptyset$ so all $n \in \emptyset$ which means there are no $n$ at all and the natural numbers do not exist.

That's ... not the way the universe works.... so $f(n)\ne D$ for all $n$.

.... are you *sure* we should be doing this?  I thought Cantor's argument had no specific $f$ in mind but was a proof that *no* function $\mathbb N \to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is injective.  *Obviously* $f(n) = \emptyset$ (or *any* constant function) isn't injective and I'm not sure why we are even bothering with this.

Shouldn't we cut to the chase and consider $f$ as potentially *any* function?

If $f(n) = D$ for some $D$ then if $n\in D$ then $n\not \in f(n) = D$ which is a contradiction.  And if $n\not \in D$ then $n \not \in D=f(n)$ and $n \in D$.  Also a contradiction.

But this is of course assuming that $D = \{n|n\not \in f(n)\}$ is definable by ZFC....